# How to init static size invariant array of stuct of point3d

Tags: c++, static, static-methods

I have create a header only library whose purpose is to encapsulate all pose information about a robot I have.  The library also provides a function to recalculate the values stored in the structure.  I use two array structures in the library; one that specifies the relationships between each joint and those it links to, and a second that keeps track of various spatial properties of each joint (e.g. angle etc.).
The first structure never changes (since you cannot add/remove things from the robot) and can be considered both static and constant.  The second structure can be considered static but not constant because the spatial information will depend on the state of the robot.

Whilst my implementation works, I am struggling to ascertain that I have correctly implemented this in C++ according to my intentions.  The library is meant to be used locally within a module (so there will be no concurrency issues) and I want to ensure that the memory space being used does not grow over time.  Thus I have used static assignments for the arrays.  I want to reuse the memory allocated to each of the Point3D objects, i.e. I want to overwrite existing values rather than create new objects.  Sensor readings are updated in my library using assignments as follows;

```
bodyPoints[bWorld].jointAngle.x = torsoRoll;
bodyPoints[bWorld].jointAngle.y = torsoPitch;
bodyPoints[bWorld].jointAngle.z = torsoYaw;
```

I haven't been programming in C++ for all that long and would appreciate someone with more experience commenting on what I've done.  The code needs to compile using C++03 standards.

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
Code snippets for each part of my existing code are below.

I have created an enum to define all the points and links I need to manage, which is basically a tree description of the robot.  Below are code snippets of the enum definitions:

```
    typedef enum BodyPoints {  // The verticies
        bWorld,
        jNeck,
            eCam1
        jLShoulder
    } BodyPoints;

    typedef enum BodyLinks {   // The edges
        Torso = 0,
            Head,
                Cam1,
            LUpperArm,
            RUpperArm
    } BodyLinks;
```

I have created a mapping array for the BodyLinks (the edges) using a structure that describes the connectivity information:

```
    struct BodyLinksMapping {
        const BodyLinks              name;
        const BodyLinks              parent;
        const BodyPoints             linkage;
        const std::vector<BodyLinks> children;

    };

    static BodyLinksMapping bodyMap[59]=
    {
        {Torso,      NROTBODYS,  bWorld,            {Head, LUpperArm, RUpperArm, LPelvis, RPelvis}},
        {Head,       Torso,      jNeck,             {Cam1}},
        {Cam1,       Head,       eCam1,             {}},
        {LUpperArm,  Torso,      jLShoulder,        {LLowerArm}},
    ...
    }
```

and an array for the BodyPoints (the vertices) using a structure that stores the spatial information:

```
    struct BodyPoint {
        BodyPoints          name;
        Point3D<double>     orientation;
        Point3D<double>     offset;
        Point3D<double>     jointAngle;
        Point3D<double>     rotated;
        Point3D<double>     translated;

    };

    static BodyPoint bodyPoints[53] =
    //                                         ///< -Orientation- >                   <----    Offset    ---->
    {   BodyPoint(bWorld,         Point3D<double>(  0.0,  0.0,  0.0), Point3D<double>(   0.00,   0.00,    0.00), Point3D<double>(0,0,0), Point3D<double>(0,0,0), Point3D<double>(0,0,0)  ),
        BodyPoint(jNeck,          Point3D<double>(  0.0,  0.0,  0.0), Point3D<double>(   0.00,   0.00,  126.50), Point3D<double>(0,0,0), Point3D<double>(0,0,0), Point3D<double>(0,0,0)  ),
        BodyPoint(eCam1,          Point3D<double>(  0.0,  1.2,  0.0), Point3D<double>(  58.71,   0.00,   63.64), Point3D<double>(0,0,0), Point3D<double>(0,0,0), Point3D<double>(0,0,0)  ),
        BodyPoint(jLShoulder,     Point3D<double>(  0.0,  0.0,  0.0), Point3D<double>(   0.00,  98.00,  100.00), Point3D<double>(0,0,0), Point3D<double>(0,0,0), Point3D<double>(0,0,0)  ),
    ...
    }
```

The Orientation and Offset of each Point is constant but the JointAngle, Rotated, and Translated change as the pose of the robot changes.  These dynamic data are calculated using a recursive function the library provides:

```
static inline void recalcRAD(BodyLinks body) {
...
}
```

Where the parameter represents the current link being considered.  I am using a linked-list approach when accessing elements of the arrays utilising pointers.

The Point3D class is largely based on the [NIST implementation of vector3d](https://pml.nist.gov/Scatmech/code/vector3d.h), and I'm using only a small subset of the available class methods;
`operator=` and `operator+=`, and a few methods I've defined which do 3D transformations.  Below is a summary of the Point3D class showing the methods I'm using:

```
template <class TYPE>
class Point3D {
public:
    ///
    /// The components of the vector
    ///
    TYPE x,y,z;

    /// Default class constructor
    Point3D<TYPE>() {}

    /// Assignment operator
    Point3D<TYPE>& operator=(const Point3D<TYPE>& a)
    {
        x=a.x;
        y=a.y;
        z=a.z;
        return *this;
    }

    /// Addition of vectors
    Point3D<TYPE> operator+(const Point3D<TYPE>& a) const
    {
        return Point3D<TYPE>(x+a.x,y+a.y,z+a.z);
    }

    /// Addition of vectors
    const Point3D<TYPE>& operator+=(const Point3D<TYPE>& a)
    {
        return *this = *this+a;
    }

    Point3D<TYPE> rotateZ_RAD(double theta) {

        return  Point3D<TYPE>(x*cos(theta) - y*sin(theta),
                           x*sin(theta) + y*cos(theta),
                           z);
    }

    Point3D<TYPE> rotate3D_RAD(const Point3D<double>& theta) {
        // Davenport (Tait–Bryan) chained extrinsic rotations (YPR)
        Point3D<TYPE> r = rotateZ_RAD(theta.z);
        r=r.rotateY_RAD(theta.y);
        r=r.rotateX_RAD(theta.x);
        return r;
    }
...
}
```

Comment: You are very likely looking for [Code review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: The one thing I will say is that for operator += to depend on operator + is generally backward. There is no reason for your += to both add and assign, instead have operator + make a copy and use +=.

Comment: @Tas, should I move the question?  What about SoronelHaetir's comment then?

Comment: @SoronelHaetir, I understand your critique of `operator+=` but I don't understand what you mean by the rest of your comment. (I have added the `operator+` method to the code snippet.)